# Inserir por ordem em lista em C

Tags: c, lista, inserir

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
Nodo * insertOrder(Nodo *L,Nodo *nv){
  //11,1,50,7,5
  if(L==NULL){
    return nv;
  }
  if(nv->id < L->id){
    return (insertFirst(L, nv));
  }
  int c=0;
  Nodo *aux2=L;
  Nodo *aux=NULL;
  while(L!=NULL){

    if(nv->id < L->id){
      c=1;
      aux->nseg=nv;
      nv->nant=aux;
      L->nant=nv;
      nv->nseg=L;
    }
    aux=L;//guarda o elemento anterior
    L=L->nseg;
  }
  if(c==0){
    aux->nseg=nv;
    nv->nant=aux;
  }
  return aux2;
}
```

Não estou a perceber porque a função referida não insere por ordem e já interpretei o código varias vezes.

Para 11,1,50,7,5

Devolve:
1 -> 5 -> 50

Comment: Falta um break; dentro do if do ciclo while

Comment: "Para 11,1,50,7,5 " - o que significam cada um desses valores ? "Devolve: 1 -> 5 -> 50" - e o que era suposto devolver ? O que são os dois parametros da função `insertOrder` ? Como foi definida a estrutura `Nodo` e respetivos typedefs ?

Comment: a seta é o ponteiro para o próximo elemento:1->5->7->11->50. Só faltava um break dentro do if. Já resolvi o problema

Comment: Se já resolveu o problema o ideal é colocar a solução como resposta devidamente detalhada para que uma pessoa com um problema semelhante o consiga também resolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está certo em seu comentário Manuel, falta um break em seu código, criei uma outra solução sem a necessidade da função auxiliar e com nomes mais expressivos que facilita o entendimento.

```
Nodo * inserirListaOrdem(Nodo *inicio, Nodo *novo)
{
    if(inicio == NULL)
    {
        return novo;
    }

    Nodo *p = inicio;
    Nodo *anterior = NULL;

    /*search position for insertion*/
    while(p != NULL && p->conteudo < novo->conteudo)
    {
        anterior = p;
        p = p->proximo;
    }
    /*insere elemento*/
    if(p->proximo == NULL)
    {
        p->proximo = novo;
        novo->proximo = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        anterior->proximo = novo;
        novo->proximo = p;
    }
    return inicio;
}
```